# Runtime Exec stop unexpectedly

Tags: java, c, runtime, runtime.exec

I have a little executable program in C that produce a lot of output to a file.
When I call this program with Runtime, like this:

```
Runtime r = Runtime.getRuntime();
Process p = null;

p = r.exec("./my_program -in input.file -out output.file", null, new File(System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir")));
```

When the program produce low output everything is ok, but when I call "*my_program*" with a large input it will produce a large quantity of output to the output.file, but in this case my program in Java freeze and nothing happen...

I test "*my_program*" in terminal with a lot of large inputs and everything is ok, but when I call the program in Java with Runtime.exec, the Java program freeze.

--
Thanks in advance

Comment: This article is a little old but still contains relevant information: When [Runtime Exec Won't](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-12-2000/jw-1229-traps.html).  Also, is your application a Swing application? Does the executable program finish eventually?

Comment: Runtime.exec in essence is a pipe connection, and you have to be prepared to handle multiple buffers of information.  It's a dozen or so lines to do it right.

Comment: No, my application is a Eclipse Plugin. I don't think so, because I test the same C program with the same input, but runned in terminal and works ok...

Comment: @zecapistolas: you obviously didn't read my link which states the same as answered later by ziesemer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you're reading from the Process's `.getOutputStream()` and `.getErrorStream()` if you aren't already.  Looking at your code snippet, it appears that you're just executing `.exec(...)` (and maybe waiting for it to complete with a call not shown to `.waitFor()`?).

Per http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html (emphasis added):

> The parent process uses these streams to feed input to and get output
>   from the subprocess. Because some native platforms only provide
>   limited buffer size for standard input and output streams, failure to
>   promptly write the input stream or read the output stream of the
>   subprocess **may cause the subprocess to block, and even deadlock**.

Comment: Yah, you are right... My C program has a lot of printfs, I remove them and now Runtime.exec() works ok, because the all output of C program goes to output.file... So, output stream has a little size and subprocess doesn't block! Thanks ;)