# Java InputStream - Program halts if read data isn't used

Tags: java, inputstream, ram

I'm processing frames from a video, but I'd like to discard the first X frames before actually processing the bytes. But when I do that, my program halts after reading around a specific amount of data (1 GB with 4GB RAM, and 2 GB with 8GB RAM).

As you can see, I'm not saving this data, so my program doesn't use more than 20 MB. Another funny thing is that when I actually do the processing on every frame, I don't get this error.

```
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

class Test{

    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException{

        String command = "ffmpeg -i test.mp4 -f rawvideo -pix_fmt rgb24 -vf scale=1600:900 -";
        Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
        InputStream stdout = process.getInputStream();

        byte packet[] = new byte[65536];
        long totalRead = 0;
        long byteStart = 1600*900*3*2000; //discard 2000 frames before start processing
        int nRead; //number of bytes read on each packet

        while((nRead = stdout.read(packet)) > -1){
            totalRead += (long)nRead;
            if(totalRead > byteStart){
                //write frames to memory
            }
            System.out.print(totalRead+"\r");
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Halts how?  `OutOfMemoryException` or something else?

Comment: It just halts, no message, no error.

Comment: must be an infinite while loop

Comment: If you were to run ffmpeg interactively, would it write anything to the screen while it works? Progress messages, percent complete, that sort of thing?

Comment: It's not infinite because the System.out.print message stops printing, and both process (java.exe and ffmpeg.exe) stop using the CPU. But both are still listed on Task Manager.

Comment: @Kenster: ffmpeg works fine interactively, it decompresses every frame.

Comment: That's not what I asked. Does it write progress messages to the screen while it works?

Comment: @Kenster: When it's used interactively yes, it writes progress messages, but inside my program no.

Comment: It's probably writing something to standard error and freezing when the stderr buffer fills up. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8206214/runtime-exec-stop-unexpectedly.

Answer (score 0):

As Kenster link says ([Runtime Exec stop unexpectedly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8206214/runtime-exec-stop-unexpectedly)), I wasn't handling the getErrorStream() from the process I called inside my code.

Using the first sample on this page solved my problem.(http://www.javaworld.com/article/2071275/core-java/when-runtime-exec---won-t.html?page=2)

I just added the StreamGobbler class to my code and used it after initializing the process:

```
StreamGobbler errorGobbler = new 
    StreamGobbler(process.getErrorStream(), "ERROR");
errorGobbler.start();
```